# Proof by induction: is it enough to show 0=0?

Tags: induction

Let $P_n$ be a proposition, so that $$P_n: 3+11+...+(8n-5)=4n^2-n$$
$P_1:3=4\cdot1^2-1$, $P_2:3+11=4\cdot2^2-2$ etc.

When proving $P_n\to P_{n+1}$, is it enough to show in the second induction step that, by subtracting from both sides we have $$4(n+1)^2-(n+1)=4n^2-n+(8(n+1)-5)\leftrightarrow0=0$$ and therefore $P_n\to P_{n+1}$. Or do I must rewrite $4n^2-n+(8(n+1)-5)$ to $4(n+1)^2-(n+1)$?

Comment: The second way is more elegant.

Comment: I think it is valid, but I would prefer to start with $n=1$ to avoid the argument with the empty sum.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I would normally start with n=1. I have not mentioned it, but the induction in the content of the question doesn't aim to be complete. The question is just about a little part of the proof.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, right? I also think so, but sometimes it's not practical. I am only concerned about the validity of the proof.

Comment: Yet the second way is easy: rewrite  $4n^2-n+8(n+1)-5$ as $4n^2+8n +3-n=(4n^2+8n +4)-(n+1)$.

Comment: No.  Proving $0 = 0$ doesn't prove anything.  It just proves that you didn't succeed in disproving something.  If I wanted to prove Elephants and horses were the same animal, I'd say the average number of pounds of salmon each eat in a year would be the same.  And that number for both of them is $0$.  Therefore elephants and horses are the same animal.

Comment: If you don't know that the are equal you can't $f(n) = g(n)$ so $4(n+1)^2-(n+1)=4n^2-n+(8(n+1)-5)$ so $0 = 0$.  What you have to say instead is $f(n) = 4(n+1)^2-(n+1)=$ and $g(n) = 4n^2-n+(8(n+1)-5)$. And those to terms are equal... OR you have to specify *every* step is an if and only if reasoning and works both ways.  If you have logical inferences that work only *one* way, then you can only prove in *that* direction.

Comment: @fleablood I am not proving $0=0$ I am just using it to make clear that both sides of the equation are equivalent...

Comment: You must do that the *correct* way.  And $a = b \to k = j \to 0= 0$ is the *wrong* way.  The correct way is either $a=k = j = b$ or $a=b \iff k = j \iff 0=0$.  The $\iff$ is *ESSENTIAL*.  Sorry, but I am a real hard-ass on that account.

Comment: In other words $4(n+1)^2-(n+1)=4n^2-n+(8(n+1)-5)\to0=0$ is not okay but $4(n+1)^2-(n+1)=4n^2-n+(8(n+1)-5)\leftrightarrow 0=0$ is.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, I get it. You're right on that. But $a\to b$ does not necessarily mean  $a\nLeftarrow b$ does it?

Comment: It must certainly does *not* which is *why* you absolutely *MUST* specify $\iff$.  Otherwise all you have proven is "If we assume what we want to prove we get something that is true".  What you want to do instead is "If we assume what we want to prove we get through a series of *equivalent* statements something that is true".  That *is* enough because you are proving $\iff$.  Not just $\implies$.

Comment: If you *start* by stating what needs to be proven then all your statements *must* be $\Leftarrow$ ("is implied by").  $\implies$ ("implies") are *totally* useless (because you are *starting* with what supposed to be proven and you don't know if it is true... and you end with what always know was true *anyway*).  Now it might be clear to you that you are doing $\iff$ statements which include both $\implies$ and $\Leftarrow$.  But you *must* say so.  Otherwise it is assumed you are only doing the $\implies$.  Which just won't work.

Comment: @fleablood That's right I want to show that $0=0\to a=b$ not only that $a=b\to0=0$. Basically, $a=b\to0=0$ is there only to make it clearer to see that $0=0\to a=b$. I have corrected my question.

Comment: @fleablood Btw. if I rewrite $a=b$ to $0=0$ using proven identities, doesn't it mean that I've got $a=b\to0=0$ which is equivalent to $(X\to T)\to T$ hence $X$ must be a true value?

Comment: No. Because $(F\to T)\to T$ is also true.  $X\to T$ is *always* true.  And that is exactly why this doesn't work. ( (Elephants are Horses)$\to$ Elephants eat the same amount of salmon) $\to 0 = 0$ is valid and true.

Comment: @fleablood Nvm. $(F\to T)\leftrightarrow T$ per definition.

Comment: And *YES*  that is TRUE and *THAT* works.  So $(X\leftarrow T)\leftarrow T$ *DOES* mean $X$ is true.

Comment: Sorry, I am a hard ass.  But it's a common novice problem to mangle proofs this way.  And frequently the do make an error.  You wouldn't, but *many* do try to do things like if ... blah... blah blah ... then prove $x + y = 5$ with.  $x + y = 5 \to (x+y)^2 = 25 \to...\to 0= 0$ which is of course wrong. So I do drop down like a ton of bricks on this.  Sorry.

Comment: @fleablood I think that it is great that you do that. It has corrected my error. Keep on dropping bricks on it ;>!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather
make the use of induction
extremely clear.

First of all,
I would write
$P_n: 3+11+...+(8n-5)=4n^2-n
$
as
$P_n:
\sum_{k=1}^n (8n-5)
=4n^2-n
$.
This makes the start and end terms
of the sum clear
and reduces the chance of error.

Then
I would show the step
from $P_n$
to $P_{n+1}$
like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (8n-5)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (8n-5)+8(n+1)-5
\qquad\text{split off the last term}\\
&=4n^2-n+8(n+1)-5
\qquad\text{use the induction hypothesis}\\
&=4n^2+7n+3
\qquad\text{algebra}\\
&=4(n+1)^2-(n+1)
\qquad\text{more algebra to get the right side of }P_{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

which is
$P_{n+1}$,
and we are done.

More generally,
suppose we are given
$a$ and $b$,
and we want to find
$u, v, $ and $w$ such that
$P_n:
\sum_{k=1}^n (an+b)
=un^2+vn+w
$
is true.

Arguing exactly as above,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (an+b)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (an+b)+a(n+1)+b
\qquad\text{split off the last term}\\
&=un^2+vn+w+a(n+1)+b
\qquad\text{use the induction hypothesis}\\
&=un^2+(v+a)n+w+a+b
\qquad\text{algebra}\\
\end{array}
$

$P_{n+1}$ is
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (an+b)
=u(n+1)^2+v(n+1)+w
$,
so we want

$un^2+(v+a)n+w+a+b\\
=u(n+1)^2+v(n+1)+w\\
=un^2+(2u+v)n+u+v+w.
$

Equating coefficients,
$v+a = 2u+v$
and
$w+a+b = u+v+w$.

From the first,
$u = a/2$.

From the second,
$a+b = u+v
=a/2+v$
so
$v = a/2+b$.

For your problem,
$a=8, b=-5$,
so
$u = 4, 
v=8/2-5
=-1
$.

Note that
$w$ does not seem to be
determined.
For this,
we need the initial value;
either $n=0$ or $n=1$
will work.

Using $n=0$,
the sum is empty,
so we want
$0 = w$.

Using $k=1$,
$P_1$ is
$a+b 
= u+v+w$
or
$w
=a+b-u-v
=a+b-a/2-(a/2+b)
= 0
$.

It is comforting that
both cases lead
to the same result.

Therefore
we have shown that
$\sum_{k=1}^n (ak+b)
=(a/2)n^2+(a/2+b)n
$.

This type of argument
enables us to
both discover a result
and prove it.

In some problems,
this technique
allows us to show that
a particular form
of a summation does not exist,
because the assumption
that the form exists
leads to a contradiction.

Comment: +1 for making the induction step very clear. But alternatively one can proceed as follows: assume that $P_n$ is true then substitute $n+1$ for $n$ in the equation of $P_n$. Since that equation must be true, and since it is equivalent to the equation in the proposition of $P_{n+1}$ we have that $P_n\to P_{n+1}$. Which is what I am using.

Comment: In all cases, it is equivalent to showing that $4n^2-n + (8(n+1)-5) = 4(n+1)^2-(n+1)$.